# How to show this function is not continuous?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $F: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $.

Let $F(x , y)={xy \over x^2+y^2}$ when $x , y \neq (0 , 0)$ and $F(x , y)=0$ when $x , y = (0 , 0)$.

I'm having trouble showing that this function is not continuous. I've shown that if I take $x=y$, then I will get $F(x , x)=\frac12$. Also, I know that $F$ is continuous in each variable separately.

Comment: Try approaching along the line y=2x.

Comment: Also, your notation is not correct. It should be $F(x,y)$, not $F(x \times y)$. Similarly, except for $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, which is correct, every other place where you used the"$\times$" symbol, you should have used ordered pair notation, or just a comma separator for arguments to $F$.

Comment: Also, the tag (general-toplogy) is not correct. You should replace that with (multivariable-calculus).

Comment: I didn't see that F(0,0) was defined as 0. Thus, as explained in the answer by AnalysisStudent0414, there's no need for a second path (so ignore my hint about y=2x).

Comment: @quasi Sorry, I just wrote as it was in my book, and my topology course gave this question as part of the problem sets. So I thought it was more of a topology question.

Comment: Ok, I guess it's also a topology question (examples of how continuity can fail).

Comment: It is, anyway, a good idea to follow quasi's suggestion. It shows you the general method, finding two directions whose limit to 0 is not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have shown that $$F(x,x)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Good! But, as it is defined, you have that $F(0,0)=0$. Now, since
$$\lim_{x\to 0} F(x,x) = \frac{1}{2} \neq 0$$

you are done showing that $F$ is not continuous in $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: @AnalysisStudento414 So, by showing $F$ is not continuous at one point is enough to show that $F$ is not continuous?

Comment: Hint: look up the definition of F being continuous on its domain :) (and, anyway, yes)

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac12$ when $x=y$.

Thus, there exists a number $\epsilon=\frac12>0$, such that for all $\delta>0$, there exist points $x$ and $y$ (with $x=y$) with $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$, such that

$$\left|\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right|\ge \epsilon=\frac12$$

This is the precisely the negation of the limit, $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}=0$.

Inasmuch as the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)\ne 0$, while $f(0,0)=0$, $f$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to given you the best answer I can.  -Mark